# How to duplicate a panel of control dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, duplicates, panel

I want to duplicating panel with same style of other panel depend on integer.

For example

```
Integer = 3
```

so I have the original panel and copy it three time with the same style using C#

Comment: Build a UserControl and create `n` instances of it

Comment: can you give me the code?

Comment: What code? Build a UserControl, in its designer add the same Controls you have in that Panel, same layout (you can copy / paste them). When you're asked to produce some copies, just loop from `0` to `n-1`, creating a new instance of that UserControl per iteration, add it to a container, e.g., a FlowLayoutPanel. That's all

Answer (score 1):

You can clone control in WinForms using `PropertyInfo[]`.
**Here is a method to duplicate panel control:**

```
private Panel GetClonedPanel(Panel panel)
{
    PropertyInfo[] controlProperties = typeof(Panel).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    Panel cloned = Activator.CreateInstance<Panel>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in controlProperties)
    {
        if (propInfo.CanWrite)
        {
            if (propInfo.Name != "WindowTarget")
                propInfo.SetValue(cloned, propInfo.GetValue(panel, null), null);
        }
    }

    return cloned;
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int inTeger = 3;
    int x = panel1.Location.X;
    for (int i = 0; i <= inTeger; i++)
    {
        // Clone the control
        Panel cloned = GetClonedPanel(panel1);
        x = x + cloned.Width + 2;
        // Add it to the form
        cloned.Location = new Point(x, panel1.Location.Y);
        this.Controls.Add(cloned);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hello, I try this but I meet some problem. It doesn't copy all style of the panel, can you help me fix this?

Comment: I use guna2Panel, it doesn't copy the border radius and fill color. Also how to copy object which is in panel?

Comment: Can you also set the code can let me control the panel separately